# Upgrading from angular 7 to 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I am upgrading from angular 7 to 12 and got all these issues.

The problem is Angular Material

How can I solve this.

```
./src/app/material.module.ts:13:89-110 - Error: export 'MatAutocompleteModule' (imported as 'MatAutocompleteModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:112-126 - Error: export 'MatBadgeModule' (imported as 'MatBadgeModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:128-148 - Error: export 'MatBottomSheetModule' (imported as 'MatBottomSheetModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:150-165 - Error: export 'MatButtonModule' (imported as 'MatButtonModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:167-188 - Error: export 'MatButtonToggleModule' (imported as 'MatButtonToggleModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:190-203 - Error: export 'MatCardModule' (imported as 'MatCardModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:205-222 - Error: export 'MatCheckboxModule' (imported as 'MatCheckboxModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:224-238 - Error: export 'MatChipsModule' (imported as 'MatChipsModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:240-256 - Error: export 'MatStepperModule' (imported as 'MatStepperModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:258-277 - Error: export 'MatDatepickerModule' (imported as 'MatDatepickerModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:279-294 - Error: export 'MatDialogModule' (imported as 'MatDialogModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:296-312 - Error: export 'MatDividerModule' (imported as 'MatDividerModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:314-332 - Error: export 'MatExpansionModule' (imported as 'MatExpansionModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:334-351 - Error: export 'MatGridListModule' (imported as 'MatGridListModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:353-366 - Error: export 'MatIconModule' (imported as 'MatIconModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:[93m13:368-382 - Error: export 'MatInputModule' (imported as 'MatInputModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:384-397 - Error: export 'MatListModule' (imported as 'MatListModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:399-412 - Error: export 'MatMenuModule' (imported as 'MatMenuModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:414-433 - Error: export 'MatNativeDateModule' (imported as 'MatNativeDateModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:435-453 - Error: export 'MatPaginatorModule' (imported as 'MatPaginatorModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:455-475 - Error: export 'MatProgressBarModule' (imported as 'MatProgressBarModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:477-501 - Error: export 'MatProgressSpinnerModule' (imported as 'MatProgressSpinnerModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:503-517 - Error: export 'MatRadioModule' (imported as 'MatRadioModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:519-534 - Error: export 'MatRippleModule' (imported as 'MatRippleModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:536-551 - Error: export 'MatSelectModule' (imported as 'MatSelectModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:553-569 - Error: export 'MatSidenavModule' (imported as 'MatSidenavModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:571-586 - Error: export 'MatSliderModule' (imported as 'MatSliderModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:588-608 - Error: export 'MatSlideToggleModule' (imported as 'MatSlideToggleModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:610-627 - Error: export 'MatSnackBarModule' (imported as 'MatSnackBarModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:629-642 - Error: export 'MatSortModule' (imported as 'MatSortModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:644-658 - Error: export 'MatTableModule' (imported as 'MatTableModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:660-673 - Error: export 'MatTabsModule' (imported as 'MatTabsModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:675-691 - Error: export 'MatToolbarModule' (imported as 'MatToolbarModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:693-709 - Error: export 'MatTooltipModule' (imported as 'MatTooltipModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)

./src/app/material.module.ts:13:711-724 - Error: export 'MatTreeModule' (imported as 'MatTreeModule') was not found in '@angular/material' (possible exports: ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround)
```

Comment: How did you update the Angular application? Have you followed [Angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=7.0-12.0)

Answer (score 7):

From Angular Material v9, each module should be imported from a separated path, e.g:

```
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
```

If you updated your Angular app using `ng update` (it's recommended to update Angular using `ng update`, but it's not recommended to move across multiple major versions, [see here for more details](https://update.angular.io/?v=7.2-12.0)), it will be migrated automatically, and you don't need to do anything regarding the import.